# Ember get sorted content in another controller

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.ArrayController that gets it's model from the route and applies some sorting.
Example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return [Ember.Object.create({id: 23, name: "John"}),
            Ember.Object.create({id: 534, name: "Warren"}),
            Ember.Object.create({id: 234, name: "Katy" })
     ];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ["id"],
    sortAscending: true

});
```

When I call the correspondant template and loop through the IndexController the sorted content is shown as expected.
However if I retrieve the content of this controller in another controller with `this.get("controllers.index.content");` and show it in it's template the sorting is not applied. Why is that? I thought that `this.get("controllers.index.content");` would retrieve the same `content` that the orignal controller is retrieving, therefore, the sorted content. How could I retrieve the same sorted content on the other controller aswell?
Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nairam/uEAEh/)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arrangedContent property, instead of content, for the sorted content:

```
this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent");
```

Comment: Wow! This is easy! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: However I just noticed that getting the content of another controller with `this.get("controllers.index.content")` or `this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent")` doesn't work (it returns "undefined" when using the local storage adapter on the backend. Is this a bug?

Comment: It works in your jsfiddle if you substitute arrangedContent for content. If you can not get even the content then something is wrong.

Comment: Both `this.get("controllers.index.content")` and `this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent")` work in this example. But if I use the ember-local-storage-adapter (together with ember-data of course) to store the models, both of the above methods don't work at all. Here's the other [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nairam/gpEFF/) with localstorage on the backend. I've also opened another question for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065647/ember-getting-content-from-another-controller-doesnt-work-with-local-storage-ad) Do you have any idea why this doesn't work?