# Ember getting content from another controller doesn't work with local storage adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Getting content from another controller via `this.get("controllers.index.content")` or `this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent")` (for sorted content) doesn't  work when using the ember-localstorage-adapter on the backend.
For example, getting content from another controller:

```
App.StartController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
needs: 'index',
someFunction: function() {
    // get the "content" from the IndexController
    var names = this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent");
    alert(names.objectAt(0).name); // should display the name property from
first stored object(if there are any stored in local storage of course),
instead, it always returns "undefined"
}
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Here's an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nairam/gpEFF/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same problem as in [Ember loop through content of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089198/ember-loop-through-content-of-controller)

you have to use

```
alert(names.objectAt(0).get('name'));
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That works. However I still need some clarification: If I use objectAt(0) it still doesn't work and returns `undefined`. If I change it to objectAt(1) it returns the **first** stored model. Does objectAt() and the underlaying array work with a non-zero based index?? Thanks!