# Ember loop through content of controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to loop through the content that I fetched from another controller and modify some properties with `forEach()`.  However this doesn't work and any attempt to get a property
in the `forEach` loop returns `undefined`.
So here's what I've tried to do:

- I'm getting the content with `this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent")`.
  The content is an array of records which is stored with local-storage-adapter.
- My model:

  ```
  App.Data = DS.Model.extend({  
  name: DS.attr('string')  
  });
  ```

In my controller:

```
App.StartController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
needs: 'index',
alert: function() {
    // get the "content" from the IndexController;
    var names = this.get("controllers.index.arrangedContent");
    var formattedNames = [];

    names.forEach(function(item) {
    var name = item.name; // <--returns "undefined"
    name += "!";
    formattedNames.push(name);
   });

   alert(formattedNames[0] );   
}
});
```

**Question**: Is there a way to access the property "name" in the `forEach` loop which returns the correct value that is stored on the model?

Note: First I thought this would be a bug on the local storage adapter, so I tried the same thing with the "fixture adapter" on the backend but this doesn't work also.
*However* if I hard-code some model instances on the router like:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return [Ember.Object.create({id: 523, name: "John"}),
            Ember.Object.create({id: 534, name: "Warren"}),
            Ember.Object.create({id: 234, name: "Katy" })
     ];
}
});
```

getting the name property in the `forEach` loop works.  Why doesn't this work when using ember-data?

Any hints/suggestions are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: how do you loop through this model in the template? **{{#each model as |item|}}**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access any content you need to use the accessor (get/set) methods at all times:

```
var name = item.get('name');
```

For what you want to accomplish, there is a better way:

```
var formattedNames = names.map(function(item, index, enumerable) {
    return item.get('name') + "!";
});
```